# DNN Cannot Edit Page or Add Module

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am working on a dnn 7.4 site, and on 1 page I cannot enter edit mode, or add modules to it.  This 1 page has a new skin that I am developing.  All other pages function fine.

When I try to go to edit mode, the page just reloads once.

When I try to add a module, it refreshes over and over again until I navigate away.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Without some code to look at this is hard to diagnose but here are the things I would try

1. remove any javascript/jquery from the skin
2. one by one remove any registered controls
3. strip down any other elements

Test as you go through each step to find the issue

In my experience its usually something in jquery that messes up the control panel

Comment: I am having an issue with DNN. I am using DNN version 7.04. I have a source code using DNN reference in it. If I change any code in that source code, it doesn't affect the source code. When I debug, it doesn't even recognize the changes I have made to the source code. Do you have any idea on that.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I figured out that the page was not in edit mode. I had to re-select the Edit Page option from the control panel and it stopped.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get into Edit mode to manipulate the page because of a bad module, you may have to resolve the problem by removing modules from the page by hand directly in the database.  But be sure to know what you are doing, you could mess things more up here.

If you know the TabId of the page you are having trouble with you can isolate the active modules in the page by running this query f.ek., through MS Sql management studio or similar tool, (where 117 is an example tabid):
select * from TabModules where TabId = 117  and IsDeleted = 'False'

Now copy the "TabModuleID" column into notepad... keeping all the Ids of active Tab modules in the page on the side.

Now run this update to disable all modules in the page:
update TabModules set IsDeleted = 'True' where TabId = 117 and IsDeleted = 'False'

Now open a command window on the server and run IISreset
(to clear up all cached data).

Then open the problem page in the webbrowser.  Now you hopefully have a running page, but missing all the modules.

Now add the modules back, one by one, by running this update for each of the ids you saved into notepad:

update TabModules set IsDeleted = False where TabId = 117 and IsDeleted = False
and TabModuleId = 99

(here 99 represents one of the TabModuleIds you saved on the side in notepad).
Refresh the page in between updates to see the modules come back.  Its possible you have to run IISreset in between too to see changes.

When the page fails again, you have found the bad module.  Disable it again by changing IsDeleted = 'False' to 'True'.

Add the remaining modules.